# Additional empty blob created with folder names in Azure storage container-not able to delete

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Whenever I create a folder or subfolder inside my azure container,it is creating additional empty blobs in it. It is a blob storage with hierrachial namespace disabled-is that the cause?

Also I am not able to delete them using the delete activity in ADF. The activity shows success but doesnt removes those files.

Comment: How are you creating the folders and subfolders? Can you provide some specific examples of your workflows for creating and deleting these items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Azure blob storage does not support having empty folders. Thus, when you try to create folders (or empty folders), there will be a duplicate empty file. The following is a demonstration where I have tried to replicate this issue.

[image]

- However, I was able to delete that specific file by selecting it in dataset using delete activity.

> It is a blob storage with hierrachial namespace disabled-is that the cause?

- Yes, enabling hierarchical workspace will enable azure data lake which supports file and directory semantics and therefore which wouldn't create that additional file.

Comment: Doesnt the Delete activity delete the folders also with same name?

Comment: No, Select the required file you want to delete using dataset browser and only that will be deleted